# DotNetBrowser unhandled exception during execution

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception, dotnetbrowser

I've developed a multithreading WPF application which is using one instance of DotNet component (namespace WPF.DotNetBrowser).

The application was running during about 21 hours of nonstop work, and then it crashed.

An undandled exeption was raised in .dll library (which was added using the docs). Visual Studio Warning (which usually describes raised exceptions) shows:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'lld.reworBteNtoD ni derrucco'
```

And further description was:

```
Additional information: Failed to send message GetDeviceScaleFactorMessage {type=GetDeviceScaleFactor, uid=3719442, deviceScaleFactor=0}.
```

Finally the application went to break mode and the 'output' tab contained the following

```
An undandled exception of type '' occured in DotNetBrowser.dll
```

So it couldn't even determine the type of exception that had been raised. I think it happens because the exception was raised in the dll file.

How can I work around this? VS was running under admin rights and the application can crash unexpectedly at any time of it's execution.

Comment: Do you use heavyweight rendering mode? Also, could you please clarify if you used mousewheel or InputSimulator.SimulateMouseWheelEvent for page scrolling?

Comment: Yes. I remember that I definitely used mousewheel (not emitted simulation events in the code). But the first time when I faced with this kind of exception the app have just been running for a long time. It's like mousewheel increases the probability of this problem.

Comment: Have noting to answer about heavyweight rendening mode yet. I'll check it out.

Comment: The web site which is loading is rather weavy. I mean it is using canvas, web socket connections and according to wappalyzer hammer js (it's interesting issue in the context of mouse wheel events).

Comment: I mean the rendering mode of DotNetBrowser you used. This article describes it: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110001-lightweight-vs-heavyweight